# Error de sintaxis al redirigir con header

Tags: php

Intento hacer una redirección con `header` de esta manera:

```
header('location:perfil.php?CodUsua=<?php echo $_SESSION['CodUsua']; ?>');
```

Recibo el siguiente fallo:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'CodUsua' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

¿Cuál sería la sintaxis correcta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás haciendo `header`, eso quiere decir que ya estás en PHP. No hace falta que vuelvas a abrir `<?php` ni escribir con `echo`. Por eso recibes el error de sintaxis.

Para solucionarlo: simplemente concatena la variable de sesión a la cadena que ya tienes usando el operador `.`:

```
header('location:perfil.php?CodUsua=' . $_SESSION['CodUsua']);
```

Comment: me acaba de dar este error

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Comment: @CarlosBonilla Quita el `echo`. Estaba editando la pregunta para quitarlo

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda enserio me sirvio